# Java/Swagger : Generate request example

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I am trying to complete the swagger documentation on the Java API I currently work on.

I want to add an example of the request's body inside the controllers, without having to write the example as a JSON string for each endpoint.

Is there a way to generate the value of the example of the annotation `@ApiParam` directly from the model of the expected object?

Example of what I could but wont do:

```
@ApiParam(name = "newObject", value = "A new object", required = true,
 examples = @Example(value = @ExampleProperty(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "{\"field\":\"value\", \"subobject\":{\"field\":\"value\"}}")))
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:

- On application startup before swagger is initialised, create objects of all models and populate them with sample data. You can use some library ([Podam](https://github.com/mtedone/podam) or any other) to do this.
- Convert these objects to a JSON String and assign to a static variable in a class
- Use this variable in your `@ApiParam` annotation, something like

```java
@ApiParam(name = "newObject", value = "A new object", required = true,
 examples = @Example(value = @ExampleProperty(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = SomeClass.JSON_VALUE_VARIABLE)))
```